# Setting up local development for Postgres Ruby-on-Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm trying to start working on an existing RubyRails app, I've got RVM, Rails and PostgreSQL set up. I've tested rails server on a test app I made, I can connect to `localhost:3000` just fine. When I copy over the existing app I'm trying to work on, `cd` to it and run `rails server`, `localhost:3000` gives me

```
PG::ConnectionBad
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I've looked for a few hours across Google and SO and can't find a proper solution. What I tried after a lot of reading was changing my `pg_hba.conf` file for postgres to have the following settings:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

I saved these changes and restarted the terminal (to reload these changes), and I am getting the same error on `localhost:3000`, the `PG:ConnectionBad` error. Could anyone lend a hand? This is so frustrating.

In case it helps, I'm using `Ruby 2.1.1` and `Rails 4.1.0` and `PostgreSQL 9.3` Thank you!

Comment: *"restarted the terminal (to reload these changes)"*. That doesn't work. You need to reload the PostgreSQL service (`pg_ctl reload` or `SIGHUP` the postmaster), or restart the computer if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: Restarting the terminal is not enough. Try `service postgresql restart`

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments, I use the above `service postgresql restart` to restart properly, thanks for that. Now I have an error that says the database is not created, I'll give it a few tries myself and post back. Thanks for the help so far everyone!

Comment: Update: I got the database working, the site loads perfectly now. I can finally start developing. Thank you so much @p11y  Make an answer  so I can choose it!

Comment: @Karysto great news, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the terminal is not enough. You can restart Postgres with

```
service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no password specified for the database:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

You can see how you specify username and password for your database here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: I made a user with no password, so I do not want to enter a password. I'm going to try the above comments and update everyone. Thanks for the help